# Javascript in the browser console running in one task to fill formulars in a webside witch is multiple times reloded with different post variables

Tags: javascript, console

**A block of Javascript Code in  the browser console running in one task to fill formulars in a webside witch is multiple times reloded with different post variables**

I want JavaScript running in the browser console performing formula filling on multiple versions of the same website changed dependent of post parameters. I make this on a site, witch i do not own.
The problem is that, after the first reload of the website, the JavaScript code is gone in the console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Entering code into the console will not result in any persistent Javascript changes, except for those made to storage (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, etc).

If you want to fiddle with a website which isn't your own, and have your custom Javascript run on every pageload, use a userscript instead. You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en). Then you can write a userscript where the `@include` property matches the site you want the userscript to run on:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Do Something
// @include          https://example.com
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('doing something');
```

This will run the custom code (here, a log of `doing something` in the console) every time `example.com` is loaded.

Comment: is it JavaScript code in the user script?
Is there an opportunity without an addon, (you mentioned  (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies)

Comment: Yes, all the code you put in the userscript is plain, ordinary Javascript, just as if you were typing it into the console (for the most part). No, this is not possible without an extension. You can use Javascript to set stuff into storage, but once the page reloads, unless the page already has a mechanism to read data from storage and execute it as Javascript (which would be exceedingly strange), modifying storage won't help you do what you want. (I was just saying that storage is *persistent*, unlike code you type into the console)

Comment: is there any other way to do this?
because my boss don't like new software.

Comment: No, there is no other way. If you want to be able to run Javascript automatically on a page which isn't yours, you'll need your browser to be customized somehow - whether that's through your own build of a browser, or through an extension, etc.